# iPhone - UILocalNotification as alarm

Tags: iphone, alarm, uilocalnotification

Even when my iPhone application is in background, How can I use UILocalNotification to show my alram every day at 8.00 PM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `fireDate` to 8.00 PM and set the `repeatInterval` to `NSDayCalendarUnit` and schedule the alert with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: myNotification];`

Comment: Is it possible to force the UILocalNotification to make sound even the phone is set to silent mode?

Comment: will this work even when the app is not running in back ground?

Comment: @AnthonyChan UILocalNotification makes a sound only when the phone is Not in silent mode.

Answer (score 2):

dasdom answer is correct. just wanted to add to it that the alarm will not make a sound if your device is in silent mode. It is a restriction from Apple for UILocalNotification.

Comment: As it should be! I don't want any app to be nosy when I want the phone to be silent!

Answer (score 0):

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification =[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

 NSCalendar *calendar=[NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];

    unsigned currentFlag=NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *comp=[calendar components:currentFlag fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    comp.hour=8;
    comp.minute=0;
    comp.second=0;

    NSDate *date=[[calendar dateFromComponents:comp]dateByAddingTimeInterval:0];

    if (localNotification==nil) {
        return;
    }

    localNotification.fireDate=date;
    localNotification.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.repeatCalendar=[NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    localNotification.alertBody=@"Good Morning dude..!";

    localNotification.alertAction=@"Snooze";

    localNotification.repeatInterval=NSDayCalendarUnit;

    localNotification.soundName=@"goodmorning.caf";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

> I hope this will help you...!