# How I can open native alarm clock in iphone by using code?

Tags: iphone, alarm

I have to crate a sample app in which when I clicked a button that should open the native alarm clock so that user can use it for setting alarm?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696346/iphone-uilocalnotification-as-alarm

check it for some help

Comment: **One** question/exclamation mark or **none**. There is never a situation where it is appropriate to use multiple. This is never good:???/!!!

Comment: Thank You , I will take care of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Clock app supported a URL scheme, like the Phone app’s `tel://` or the Mail app’s `mail://`, you could open it with the standard `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"..."]]` approach. Unfortunately, to my knowledge, it doesn’t, so all you can really do is prompt the user to open that app themselves to set up the alarm.

Alternatively, you can have your app set up a local notification to *act* as an alarm using UILocalNotification, which you can find plenty of information about by [searching this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uilocalnotification+alarm).

Comment: I have Google it a lot to do this , i knew the others way using local notification and using timer but i want to it as my Question. Thanks A Lot for help....

Comment: As we use native MFMailComposer from Library we just use it it will open the native mailcomposer directly for sending the mail , in the same way i want to do with alarm. Is there any library ?? i searched it for also but failed to get this.

Comment: There is not. You can file an enhancement request for the iOS SDK at http://bugreport.apple.com if you’d like them to add one.

Comment: Thank You for your valuable suggestion .

Answer (score 3):

For default app MobileClock.app exists several url scheme. If u have a look in system files and open content for MobileClock.app u will find in info.plist private url scheme:

- clock-worldclock,
- clock-alarm,
- clock-stopwatch,
- clock-timer,
- clock-timer-running
  .

Which using them should be possible to run app externally but only from Today widgets. Also the same for the mobile notes app.

Answer (score 2):

## Two steps required.

#### Add the URL to info.plist CFBundleURLSchemes

```
<array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>clock-alarm</string>
                <string>clock-stopwatch</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
</array>
```

#### Call sharedApplication's openURL

```objc
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
  openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"clock-alarm:"]];
];
```