# How can I launch the iOS Clock app using a a URL scheme?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-scheme

How do I redirect to home screen clock on click button event in my app?

I am trying with this code, but it redirects to Settings page, whereas I want to redirect to clock page.

This is my code which I used in my project:-

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General&path=Clock"]]
```

please give some ideas.thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How I can open native alarm clock in iphone by using code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722683/how-i-can-open-native-alarm-clock-in-iphone-by-using-code)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** it is **not** possible to do this.

There are URL schemes for the various parts of the Clock app (see below) but for some reason they do not work.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

As far as I know the Clock app has several URL schemes depending on the part of the app to launch to.

Try this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"clock-worldclock://"]]
```

`clock-alarm://` and `clock-stopwatch://` should also work.

Comment: Its not working. I tried this code on click button event but its not redirect to clock. I stuck with this problem so many days.Please help me out.

Comment: i tried this code but its not redirect to clock where as i want to redirect clock on click button event. please help me, i stuck in this problem so many days. i tried this on also :  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"reminder:%@", reminder]]];
    NSString *alarmstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"reminder:%@",reminder];
    NSURL *alarmurl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:alarmstr];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:alarmurl];

Comment: Sorry, looks like it's in fact not possible to launch the clock app from code.

Comment: then sir how would i redirect to home screen on click button?? have any chance??

Comment: The only way to go to the home screen would be to call `exit(0)` which will exit the app. However, this is against the App Store rules so your app is likely to be rejected if you do this.

Comment: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"timer://"]];` doesn't work too. There are list of URL Schemes http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes