# Can I create a countdown but using the native iPhone app?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple question. I want to know if I can redirect users from the app im building up to the native app to set up a countdown. I mean, I want in my app to appear "Set a 30 minutes countdown" and when clicked open up the clock app with the 30 minutes started. Is it that possible or do I have to create the countdown functionality in my app?

Comment: you have to create an  countdown function in our app only. you can do one that like you can add an event to calender with 30m of current time

Answer (score 1):

Best you can do is "donate" a shortcut that starts a timer to the Shortcuts app for the user to manually invoke via Siri.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit

Apple has not exposed any APIs to interact with the built-in clock app -- in fact, I can't seem to launch it anymore via deeplinks in iOS 17.x. (This used to work: [How I can open native alarm clock in iphone by using code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722683/how-i-can-open-native-alarm-clock-in-iphone-by-using-code))